# Python 3 cannot import socket in CMD but available in IDLE

Tags: python, cmd

I have installed python 3.7 on my computer. It seems not possible to `import` socket in CMD:

```
C:\Users\Sina\py
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
import _socket
ImportError: Module use of python27.dll conflicts with this version of 
Python.
>>>
```

But surprisingly, I am able to import `socket` in IDLE (Python 3.7).

I searched but didn't find any 'python27.dll' file in the installation directory
of python 3.7 (C:\Python37-32)

**EDIT:** There was a _socket.pyd file at "C:\Users\Sina" which used to make the confliction. I deleted it and the problem got fixed. Thanks to Aran-Fey!

Comment: The error indicates that it is trying to import python2 version.

Comment: Where is your PYTHONPATH points to?

Comment: Check your python environment path, especially if you have multiple versions of python installed right now.

Comment: If you have any `.pyc` or `.pyd` files lying around in `C:\Users\Sina`, delete them.